# Is responsive masonry with VueJS and Bootstrap Tabs even possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, masonry

I'm using VueJS to render dynamic components with variable height in a "masonry" layout, but this often produces ugly spaces when the heights don't line up perfectly. I was hoping to use a library to handle this, but, unfortunately, the tab component's width is variable as well, which means that none of them worked adequately.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POwsZ.png)

I have:

- Vue 2.5
- [Bootstrap 3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/) (locked, no way to upgrade to 4)

Example code ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7nbsh0vp/60/)):

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="container">
    <button v-on:click="currentWidth += 50">Increase Parent Width</button>
    <button v-on:click="currentWidth -= 50">Decrease Parent Width</button>
    <div class="parent pt1" v-bind:style="{width: currentWidth + 'px'}">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li v-for="(tab, tabIndex) in tabs" role="presentation" v-bind:class="{active: tabIndex == selectedTab}">
                <a v-bind:href="tab.name" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" v-on:click="selectedTab = tabIndex">{{tab.name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div v-for="(tab, tabIndex) in tabs" role="tabpanel" v-bind:id="tab.name" class="tab-pane p1" v-bind:class="{active: tabIndex == selectedTab}">
                <div class="row">
                    <div v-for="dataPoint in tab.data" class="col-xs-6 blue">
                        <div class="green b1 vc text-center" v-bind:style="{height: randomHeight()}">
                            <h1>{{dataPoint}}</h1>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function() {
      return {
        selectedTab: 0,
        currentWidth: 500,
        tabs: [{
          name: 'tab1',
          data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        }, {
          name: 'tab2',
          data: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
        }]
      }
    },
    methods: {
      randomHeight: function() {
        return ((Math.random() * 200) + 75) + 'px'
      }
    }
  })
</script>

<style>
  .p1{
    padding: 1em;
  }
  .pt1{
    padding-top: 1em;
  }
  .b1{
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .vc{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .blue{
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
  .green{
    color: black;
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
</style>
```

I have tried multiple different masonry libraries but not had any success:

- [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/) (jQuery) - Did not work
- [Vue-Masonry](https://shershen08.github.io/vue-plugins-demo-static/index.html#/masonry) (jQuery Masonry for VueJS) - Works on load, but breaks when the tab component's width changes
- [Salvattore](https://salvattore.js.org/) (JS) - Did not work
- [Vue-Masonry-CSS](https://paulcollett.github.io/vue-masonry-css/demo/) (VueJS) - Did not work ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7nbsh0vp/61/))

I don't really know what other good solutions exist to solve this awkward formatting. Is there any other way to get my elements to align nicely in a grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this by switching to two fixed Bootstrap columns, which meant that I could fill each column with exactly half of the elements. Since the columns weren't stacked on top of each other, everything fit in nicely.

Here's an example for how to split an Array of elements to display into two:

```
splitItems: function(itemCategory) {
  let itemArray = Object.keys(this.items[itemCategory])
  let split = [[], []]
  let alternator = 0
  itemArray.forEach(item => {
    if (this.items[itemCategory][item] !== false) {
      split[alternator].push(item)
      alternator = Math.abs(alternator - 1)
    }
  })
  return split
}
```

Then you just run nested `v-for` to render each column separately.